# Return httpresponse outside of post

Tags: django, django-views

Is there a way to stop execution and return an httpresponse in a function other than post, get, put?

So for example

```
class MyClass(View):
  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      test_some_things()
      do_some_other_stuff()
      return HttpResponse(..)

  def test_some_things(self):
      if test_fails:
          return HttpResponse(..)
      else:
          return 1
```

I want to be able to end execution if test_fails and just return the response. But the above doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Sounds like a similar concept to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14329219/473232).  A view decorator might be the right approach for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Although possible, it clearer to separate these things: have one method that tests things and returns the outcome of that (boolean). Then, check whether the tests succeeded and return the response in the view.

This will make your code a lot easier to maintain and test in the long run.

What your propose is possible but it won't lead to the simplest solution to this situation.